# jQuery tooltip random appear

Tags: jquery, random, tooltip, delay, show

I am developing this "logo colors". I need the tooltip to appear in a DIV where id is `#show` after I click (this is OK). But after hover the buttons the tooltip is appearing anywhere it wants.

Visit my problem here: http://web-stranky.org/pro_dementa/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( document ).tooltip( {
        content:  function() {
            return  $( this ).attr( "title" );
        }
    });      
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#show').html($('#' + $(this).attr('aria-describedby')).children().html());
    });
});
```

Comment: I see that you have included 2 `jquery` files one with version `1.11.3` and other with version `1.6.2` which gives the console error `.on('click'` is not a function. Duly note this!! and you have to keep only one version of `jquery`  and it would be good if you use latest version

Comment: Sorry old version. Now is actual.
Thanks for your point.

Comment: So you are using old version?

Comment: the "function" -on('click'.. is not problem. This rows are for change colors. i need just show the tittle of each buttons in one div :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not included `jquery-ui.css`. Just add it in document and everything will be fine!!

You can get it from **[here](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/11/jquery-ui-1-9-2/)**

**UPDATE**

If you need it in the div the along with `html` add `title` attribute too and as below remove the title attribute from other elements

```
$('#show').html($('#' + $(this).attr('aria-describedby')).children().html());

$('#show').attr('title',$('#' + $(this).attr('aria-describedby')).children().html()); //add this
```

Comment: still not working. prolem after hover the buttons with title=""

Comment: You have included `jquery-ui.js` twice now instead of **`jquery-ui.css`**

Comment: Now its working..thanks.. but i have still the title near the cursor...i need it only in the div with id <pre>#show</pre>

Comment: @ErikMargony Updated the answer!! check it and let me know and if this has helped you do not forget to mark it as answer so that in future others find this post useful!!